# Error NodeStore has no Model

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm using a TreeGrid to display some data. 
Since I implemented the treegrid, extjs keeps throwing this error:

*Store defined with no model. You may have mistyped the model name.*

I debugged a bit and found out, that this is thrown because there is a "nodeStore" without model.

Where does this "nodeStore" come from and what am I doing wrong?

Store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.AdvertiserStatistics', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'AM.model.AdvertiserStatistic',
    autoLoad: false,
    folderSort: true,
    startDate: new Date().getTime(),
    endDate: new Date().getTime(),
    nodeType: 'weekly',
    parentId: null,
    [..]
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.AdvertiserStatistic', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {
        name:'id',
        type:'int',
        useNull:true
    },
    'email',
    'clientname',
],
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    reader:{
        type:'json',
    root:'data'
    },
    api:{
    read:BASE_PATH + 'advertisers/index/stats:true/',
    destroy: BASE_PATH + 'advertisers/index/stats:true/'
    },
    base_api: {}
}
});
```

Comment: did you set the model property in your store? Please share code of the store declaration

Comment: Please see my code. My data is loaded properly but I'm curious where this error comes from.

Comment: See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293511/how-to-specify-model-name-in-store-of-an-extjs-4/9295119#9295119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this elsewhere, but I think this question will be easier to find for people who do the debugging as you have:

This is a bug in NodeStore. You will always see this when you use a Tree Panel.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's one or not. You could check on the Ext forums. I've largely ignored the issue as it's not actually harmful.

Answer (score 0):

The only guess I have - is that you forgot to add your model into the models collection of you MVC app. You could also try to set require property in your store. Just put the same string as for the model property.

```
Ext.define('AM.store.AdvertiserStatistics', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'AM.model.AdvertiserStatistic',
    require: 'AM.model.AdvertiserStatistic', //this!
    autoLoad: false,
    folderSort: true,
    startDate: new Date().getTime(),
    endDate: new Date().getTime(),
    nodeType: 'weekly',
    parentId: null,
    [..]
```